# Can't get any Transitions to work with Popup in UWP

Tags: c#, xaml, popup, uwp, uwp-xaml

I trying to change the appearance of a Popup in a UWP App but I'm having trouble using any Transitions. Basically, the XAML parser throws an exception whatever Transition I use.

Please can someone help tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Here is some example XAML that blows up:

```
<Grid Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
    <Popup x:Name="popup" IsOpen="True">
        <Popup.Transitions>
            <PopupThemeTransition FromHorizontalOffset="100"/>
        </Popup.Transitions>
        <Border Background="Red" Width="100" Height="100"/>
    </Popup>
</Grid>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The type of [UIElement.Transitions property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.uielement.transitions) value should be [TransitionCollection](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.media.animation.transitioncollection). We cannot directly give a [PopupThemeTransition](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.media.animation.popupthemetransition) to `Popup.Transitions`. You code snippet is lacking of the `TransitionCollection` element. Right using as follows:

```
<Popup x:Name="StandardPopup" >
    <Popup.Transitions>
        <TransitionCollection>
            <PopupThemeTransition FromHorizontalOffset="100"/>
        </TransitionCollection>
    </Popup.Transitions>
    <Border Background="Red" Width="100" Height="100"/>
</Popup>
```

Comment: that's great - Thanks!

Comment: @danbord, ask a new thread with your minimal reproduced project.