# UWP - Animate PopUp opening and closing

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp, popup, uwp-xaml

Looking for help on how to animate the entrance/exit of a Popup. Haven't found any examples specific to using a StoryBoard for this--does anyone know of one?

I found this question:
[Can't get any Transitions to work with Popup in UWP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40594434/cant-get-any-transitions-to-work-with-popup-in-uwp). An answer there links to some intriguing articles, which leads to [Animating pop-up UI](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/apps/jj649433(v=win.10)). There's a link to a "XAML personality animations sample", which shows how to use a StoryBoard to customize the animation, but it looks like that sample is gone.

Answer (score 0):

The sample you mentioned is a Windows 8 sample. You could now find it here:[XAML personality animations sample](https://github.com/microsoftarchive/msdn-code-gallery-microsoft/tree/master/Official%20Windows%20Platform%20Sample/XAML%20personality%20animations%20sample).

If you want to animate the PopUp, you will need to add the [PopInThemeAnimation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/Windows.UI.Xaml.Media.Animation.PopInThemeAnimation?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=winrt-22621) and [PopOutThemeAnimation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/Windows.UI.Xaml.Media.Animation.PopOutThemeAnimation?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=winrt-22621) in the resources of the PopUp. Then call the animation to begin when you show the PopUp. I've made a simple demo about this.

**XAML:**

```
    <Grid>
    <StackPanel>
        <Button Content="Show Popup (using Offset)" Click="ShowPopupOffsetClicked" ToolTipService.ToolTip="Simple ToolTip"/>
    </StackPanel>
    
    <Popup VerticalOffset="100" HorizontalOffset="100" x:Name="StandardPopup">
        <!--add the animataion for PopUp-->
        <Popup.Resources>
            <Storyboard x:Name="PopInStoryboard">
                <PopInThemeAnimation  Storyboard.TargetName="StandardPopup" FromHorizontalOffset="500"/>
            </Storyboard>
            <Storyboard x:Name="PopOutStoryboard">
                <PopOutThemeAnimation  Storyboard.TargetName="StandardPopup" />
            </Storyboard>
        </Popup.Resources>
        
        <Border BorderBrush="{StaticResource ApplicationForegroundThemeBrush}" 
            Background="{StaticResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}"
            BorderThickness="2" Width="200" Height="200">
            <StackPanel HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center">
                <TextBlock Text="Simple Popup" FontSize="24.667" HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
                <Button Content="Close" Click="ClosePopupClicked" HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
            </StackPanel>
        </Border>
    </Popup>
    
</Grid>
```

**Code-behind:**

```
 private void ClosePopupClicked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        //disappear
        PopOutStoryboard.Begin();
    }

    // Handles the Click event on the Button on the page and opens the Popup. 
    private void ShowPopupOffsetClicked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        PopInStoryboard.Begin();
        // open the Popup if it isn't open already 
        if (!StandardPopup.IsOpen) { StandardPopup.IsOpen = true; }
    }
```

Comment: Can I also do as in the linked question:
<Popup x:Name="StandardPopup" >
    <Popup.Transitions>
        <TransitionCollection>
            <PopupThemeTransition FromHorizontalOffset="100"/>
        </TransitionCollection>
    </Popup.Transitions>
    <Border Background="Red" Width="100" Height="100"/>
</Popup>

Comment: When I add that, nothing happens. Shouldn't it just work when the Popup is triggered?

Comment: This doesn't animate the Popup closing. The Popup snaps off before the animation runs. How do I fix this?

Comment: The PopOutThemeAnimation  and PopInThemeAnimation are used for a grid control not a PopUp in the sample you posted.   https://github.com/microsoftarchive/msdn-code-gallery-microsoft/blob/master/Official%20Windows%20Platform%20Sample/XAML%20personality%20animations%20sample/%5BC%23%5D-XAML%20personality%20animations%20sample/C%23/Scenario1.xaml Trying to make an StoryBoard animation that directly control the popup should be better.